# Logs are getting added to both defult and customer file appender

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have written a logging utility where I have a default logger (let's say L1) which is initialized from a logconfig.yaml file and when L1 is used, the logs are written to "l1_logfile.log". In addition, I have defined another logger (let's say L2) with its own appender handler such that when used L2, the log messages are written to a file "l2_logfile.log".

The L1 logger initialized using the following static configuration (from logconfig.yaml file) and is initialized by using -- logging.config.dictConfig(config).

```
version: 1

formatters:
  json_formatter:
    format: '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s [%(threadName)s] %(name)s %(filename)s:%(funcName)s %(message)s'
    class: pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter

handlers:
  file_handler:
    class: logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
    formatter: json_formatter
    filename: ../logs/logfile.log
    maxBytes: 10485760 # 10MB
    backupCount: 20

loggers:
  my_module:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [file_handler]
    propagate: no

root:
  level: DEBUG
  handlers: [file_handler]
```

The L1 logger and its configurator are shown below.

```
def setup_logging(path):
    with open(path, 'rt') as f:
        try:
            multiprocessing_logging.install_mp_handler()
            config = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
            logging.config.dictConfig(config)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error in Logging Configuration. Using default configs')
            logging.basicConfig(filemode='w', level=DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL)
```

The L2 logger is a dynamic logger configuration and also had a custom file appender.

```
def get_custom_logger_appender(appender_name, logger_name):
    logr_name = appender_name + logger_name
    logger = logging.getLogger(logr_name)
    format_str = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s [%(threadName)s] %(name)s %(filename)s:%(funcName)s %(message)s'
    formatter = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter(format_str)
    log_file_name = os.path.join("./logs", '{}_{}.log'.format(appender_name, "appln"))
    file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(log_file_name,
                                                            maxBytes=100000,
                                                            backupCount=15)

    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    adapter = CustomAdapter(logger, {'app_context': "app_context_value"})
    return adapter
```

This is a unit test function.

```
class TestSum(unittest.TestCase):
    // Defualt configurator.
    setup_logging("./logconfig.yaml")
    
    def test_appender_log_file_created(self):
        appender_name = "appender"
        logger_name = "testlogger"
        self.logger = Logger.get_custom_logger_appender(appender_name, logger_name)
        self.logger.info("This is info log 1")
        self.logger.info("This is info log 2")
        self.logger.info("This is info log 3")
        base_dir = self.logger_config.log_base_dir()
        log_file = base_dir + "/" + appender_name + '_' + LoggerConfig.appl_name() + ".log"
        assert os.path.exists(log_file)
```

The issue is that three log messages are written to both log files "l1_logfile.log" and "l2_logfile.log" whereas these log messages should only be written to "l2_logfile.log" as they are written by the custom logger appender. What is wrong with my logic?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by implementing the get_logger() using another RotatingFileHandler. The issue was that the logger config (using the .yaml file) was also getting applied to the L2 logger instance by default. The below code helped to explicitly configure the logger.

```
def get_logger(logger_name):
  log_file_name = os.path.join("logfile.log")
  file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(log_file_name,
                                                      mode='a',
                                                      maxBytes=10*1024*1024,
                                                      backupCount=15)
  formatter = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s [%(threadName)s] %(name)s %(filename)s:%(funcName)s %(message)s')
  file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
  logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
  logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
  logger.addHandler(file_handler)
  adapter = CustomAdapter(logger, {'app_context': "app_context"})
  Logger.__logger_dict[logger_name] = adapter

  Logger.update_log_level_config(logger_name, logger.level)
  return adapter
```